# Randomizing color of svg stroke

Tags: jquery, css, object, random, svg

So I'm trying to create a feature on a website where a client would be able to upload a set of simple .svg images, and declare a set of stroke colors. The image would then appear in the background of his website in a random combination of image and stroke color.

I'm wondering if this would even be possible. What I was trying to do was call the .svg file via jquery, like

```
var images = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08'];
$('<img class="bgImg" src="../../static/images/backgroundImage-' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '.svg">').appendTo('#border');
```

and then modify its color using something like

```
$('.bgImg').css({"stroke":"black"});
```

(Although I guess I would create a second array of css color variables)

The problem though is I'm getting stuck because you can't modify the css of a .svg if its not inline svg unless you use . Within html you call the svg file with , then in the .svg file you can call an external style sheet and modify its css attributes via this stylesheet. The thing is I'm not sure if  and external style sheets would even help since I'm doing this with jquery and not html and css. So I'm wondering if anyone might have any ideas.

this was helpful to understand how  and svg work, look towards the bottom of the article:
http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 0):

If you can load the svg file as xml text, you can change the stroke attributes on paths or shapes via string manipulation.

Once you have your modified svg xml string, you could apply that svg as a background image using a data uri like so:

```
body { background-image: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'><linearGradient id='gradient'><stop offset='10%' stop-color='#F00'/><stop offset='90%' stop-color='#fcc'/> </linearGradient><rect fill='url(#gradient)' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'/></svg>");
```